How to tell if Angular reactive form input came from keyboard or programmatic input
Is there a way to tell the difference between someone entering data into a reactive form input manually through the keyboard versus setting it via the setvalue() method?

if you are talking about valuechanges then no. setValue(value, { emitEvent: false} so when you set programatically it does not bubble event ?

Check isTrusted, I haven't tried it but possibly?

Since there are no built in functions to achieve what you are looking for. So I created a work around for that. Please correct me if somethings worng. here is my code -
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;
  sub: any;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [''],
      email: [''],
      address: [''],
      calledSetValue : false,
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub = this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value=>{
      if(value['calledSetValue']===true){
        //do something
        this.myForm.get('calledSetValue')?.patchValue(false);
      }
    })
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    console.log(this.myForm.value);
  }

  setDummyData(): void {
    this.myForm.setValue({
      name: 'John Doe',
      email: 'john.doe@example.com',
      address: '123 Main St',
      calledSetValue : true,
    });
  }
}

html -
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input id="name" formControlName="name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input id="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address">Address:</label>
        <input id="address" formControlName="address" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
<button (click)="setDummyData()" class="btn btn-secondary mt-3">Set Dummy Data</button>


Here I have added a form control calledSetValue as a flag. This form control will not be linked in html.
whenever setValue function is called on form, value of calledSetValue will be set to true and in valueChanges subscription if calledSetValue is true then whatever action you want to perform will be done.
After that again calledSetValue will be set as false.


In your example we know that it's been programmatically set but what I need is to know if the entry was typed and then prevent programmatic entry.  I even set the emitEvent option on setValue() to false but there is something in the page that's triggering an update of the form and forces the control to trigger the valueChanges event

Sorry i am not getting it. if you change value of form control either programmatically or manually valueChanges event will be triggered. Can you specify in details what exactly you want?

I need to differentiate between what is user typed input versus programmatic input.  The field can be updated programmatically via a selection from a drop list so long as the user has not already typed something into the input.  I've currently solved the issue by using the keyup event on the input.
